# sqlalchemy alias for columns name also keeping the original

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have table definistion like so:

```
class A():
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    a_id = Column('a_id', INTEGER)

class B():
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    b_id = Column('b_id', INTEGER)
```

Tables have same schema except for difference in `<tablename>_id` columns and it is a common case where i need to query both together.
For legacy reasons I can't rename the class property to `id` but I can add a property. I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
class A():
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    a_id = Column('a_id', INTEGER)
    id = alias_of_column(a_id)
```

Is there anything like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sqlalchemy.orm.synonym`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#synonyms) is the most straightforward way to mirror a column on another attribute.

From the docs:

> In the most basic sense, the synonym is an easy way to make a certain
>   attribute available by an additional name...

And:

> The synonym() can be used for any kind of mapped attribute that
>   subclasses MapperProperty, including mapped columns and relationships,
>   as well as synonyms themselves.

Usage is as simple as the example in your question:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import synonym
class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    b_id = Column('b_id', INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    id = synonym('b_id')
```

This test code:

```
s.add(B(id=1))
s.commit()
print(s.query(B).filter(B.id==1).one())
```

...emitted this sql:

```
2019-03-31 20:54:05,208 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-03-31 20:54:05,209 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO b (b_id) VALUES (%(b_id)s)
2019-03-31 20:54:05,209 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'b_id': 1}
2019-03-31 20:54:05,211 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2019-03-31 20:54:05,218 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-03-31 20:54:05,219 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT b.b_id AS b_b_id
FROM b
WHERE b.b_id = %(b_id_1)s
2019-03-31 20:54:05,219 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'b_id_1': 1}
B(b_id=1)
```